# Does there exist a surjective homomorphism between every pair of monoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Say we have two monoids $N,M$ and w.l.o.g. assume that $|N| \geq |M|$.
Does there exist a surjective homomorphism $\varphi : N \to M$?

#### Context

In the category of sets the answer would be yes: there is a surjection. The question is whether a surjection can me made compatible with the monoid structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group homomorphism question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369687/group-homomorphism-question) (using that moreover, a monoid homomorphism between groups is necessarily a group homomorphism).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a homomorphism, then for any two monoids $M$ and $N$, the function $f:N\to M$ defined by $f(n)=1_M$  where $1_M$ is the identity element of $M$, is a homomorphism. This trivial homomorphism exists no matter what the sizes of $M$ and $N$ are.

However, if you want a surjective homomorphism, the answer is no: For example, there is no non-trivial homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_3$ to $\mathbb Z_2$